# LOOKUP for data from other sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

So I have a drop-down menu in **order** sheet and I have an **info** sheet.  In the info sheet, I have 2 columns, column **A** has the customer name, column **B** has the customer e-mail.

So what I'd like to do is, in the order sheet select a customer name, then the column next to it would auto-populate their e-mail address.

I have 43 customers with 43 e-mails and it's inconvenient to select the customer (IE Joe H.) and the try to find that guys e-mail from another drop-down list.  If it could auto-populate it would be nice.

Basically, I was looking at the `IF` command or `LOOKUP` command and I'm a little confused which will best suit my needs.

If column **A** in order sheets is `Joe`, then column **B** in order sheets is automatically `Joe@gmail.com`, if column **A** is `Jack` then column **B** is `Jack@yahoo.com` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, info!A2:B, 2, 0), ))
```

[image]